# Передача const char* между областями видимости функций разных потоков (C++)

Tags: c++, многопоточность, стандарт

Назрел довольно странный вопрос.

Допустим, где-то в коде я создаю C-строку `const char* szSomeStr = "Some Str"`, она даже может быть параметром какой-либо функции в которой я передаю эту строку куда-то дальше:

```
    void someFunction(const char* szParam)
    {
        anotherFunction(szParam)
    }
```

И поскольку в данном случае не происходит выделения памяти и строка нигде не копируется, то все работает быстро.

Но что если мне нужно, например, чтобы функция `someFunction` запустила `anotherFunction` в другом потоке:

```
    void someFunction(const char* szParam)
    {
        m_cThread = std::thread([&](){
            anotherFunction(szParam)
        });
        m_cThread.detach()
    }
```

В таком случае, если я все правильно понимаю, функция `someFunction` завершается, значение `szParam` становится не определено, в то время как `anotherFunction` запущенное в отдельном потоке все еще может его использовать (покуда не завершится лямбда потока).

Такой проблемы бы не было, если бы я, скопировал в отдельном потоке строку и использовал бы её.

```
    void someFunction(const char* szParam)
    {
        m_cThread = std::thread([&](){
            std::string str(szParam);
            anotherFunction(str.c_str())
        });
        m_cThread.detach()
    }
```

Также, если внутри самого потока буду передавать литерал строки, тоже не возникнет проблем:

```
    void someFunction(const char* szParam)
    {
        m_cThread = std::thread([&](){
            anotherFunction("Some string")
        });
        m_cThread.detach()
    }
```

Но мне нужно кое что другое. Мне нужно как бы "переместить" константную C-строку "между потоками". То есть, чтобы когда я, например, пишу `someFunction("MyCoolString")`, компилятор счел будто бы я вызываю функцию, тело которой:

```
{
    m_cThread = std::thread([&](){
        anotherFunction("MyCoolString")
    });
    m_cThread.detach()
}
```

То есть, чтобы эта константная строка как бы "переместилась" в область видимости того потока, и не потерялась, даже когда завершится функция `someFunction`, при этом оставшись обычной константной строкой.

Есть ли вообще в C++ какая-то такая возможность (макросы не предлагать) в стандарте? Или это не может быть возможным в силу статической природы `const char*`?

**UPD:**

Провел небольшой эксперимент, и остался немного удивлен поведением const char*.

```
std::thread g_cThread;

void firstFunction()
{
    // Указатель на строку
    const char* szSomeString = "Some text";
    // Переменная
    const int a = 5;

    // Вывод адресов переменной и строки
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(szSomeString) << std::endl;

    // Запускаем поток (передаем на этот раз по значению)
    g_cThread = std::thread([=](){
        // Ожидаем секунду
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        // Вывод адресов переменной и строки
        std::cout << reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&a) << std::endl; // Другой адрес (копирование самих данных)
        std::cout << reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(szSomeString) << std::endl; // Тот же адрес (копирование указателя)

        // Вывод строки по СТАРОМУ адресу, данные которой должны быть уничтожены (работает?!)
        std::cout << szSomeString << std::endl;
    });
    g_cThread.detach();
}

int main([[maybe_unused]] int arc, [[maybe_unused]] char* argv[])
{
    // Функция запускает поток
    firstFunction();

    // Функция завершается (уничтожая созданные внутри объекты) Ждем немного в основном потоке
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    return 0;
}
```

По каким-то причинам ДАННЫЕ не уничтожаются после завершения функции. То есть `const char*` ведет себя не так как обычные переменные, а как `new char[]` (то есть данные глобальны). Или я не прав?

Но не знаю, говорит ли это о том, что я могу безопасно передавать по значению такие строки между потоками и не париться о копировании ДАННЫХ (дабы их не потерять). А также не понятно что будет, если такая строка будет передаваться из одной DLL в другую (где вторая еще ее передаст в какой-ниубдь другой поток)..

Comment: У вас тут прям винегрет тут. Надо же различать время жизни буфера, на который указывает указатель, и время жизни самого указателя. Нет у `const char*` никакой статической природы. Захват указателя по ссылке приведет к потенциальному использованию в потоке протухшей ссылки. `m_cThread.detach()` тоже является ошибкой.

Comment: Не смешивайте время жизни указателя и данных, на которые он указывает. 1) В лямбде вы захватываете _по ссылке_ локальную переменную `szParam`. По завершении работы функции `someFunction`, лямда будет ссылаться на несуществующий указатель. Захватывайте указатель _по значению_ (`[=]`, например). 2) Строковые литералы имеют статическую продолжительность хранения. Литерал `"Some Str"` можно безопасно читать из разных потоков.

Comment: Что то мне кажется, что автор вопроса начитался страшилок от rust и теперь пытается переместить владение, но не знает, как это сделать

Comment: Хотя я не уверен, что можно обращаться к статическим объектам, если главный поток завершит свою работу.

Comment: Когда завершается главный поток, то все второстепенные тоже завершаться, приложение завершиться. я заменил тело anotherFunction на вывод строки. И тут может быть три варианта - строка будет выведена (поток успел), строка не будет выведена (поток не успел или осталось в буфере) и упало с крешем (я не успел посмотреть стек)

Comment: @KoVadim, так может упало с крешем не потому, что второстепенные потоки завершились, а потому, что главный поток разрушил статические объекты, к которым пытаются обращаться отвязанные потоки?

Comment: в данном случае я сильно-сильно сомневаюсь. си-строка скорее всего хранится прямо в памяти и для нее не нужен "сложный деструктор".

Comment: у меня есть подозрение, что упало оно потому, что detach не успел вызваться. Но повторить краш не удается. А так хотелось бы

Comment: @user7860670 Мне как раз и важно время жизни буфера (самих данных). Если я все правильно помню, то объекты созданные внутри функции, уничтожаются, после того как функция завершается. Соответственно, получается и моя C-строка должна быть тоже уничтожена (сами данные и указатель на нее). Или нет? Или же данные будут жить вечно, в то время как указатель исчезнет?

Comment: Обновил свой вопрос

Comment: При выходе из области видимости уничтожаются данные с автоматическим временем хранения. Данные в строковых литералах имеют статическое время хранения.

Comment: Строковый литерал `"some text"` — это static массив из `N` элементов типа `const char`. Здесь: `const char* szSomeString = "Some text";` вы в локальную переменную `szSomeString` сохранили адрес первого элемента статического массива. При выходе из функции переменная `szSomeString` существовать перестанет, но не статический массив.

Comment: где то встречал такую "конструкцию" - массивы в с/с++ - не value type. а вот std::array<...> - value type. Поэтому, передавая куда-то, обычные си строки не копируются (а значит и удалять не нужно), а вот std::array  ведет себя по другому

Answer (score 1):

```
void someFunction(const char* szParam)
    {
        m_cThread = std::thread([&](){
            anotherFunction(szParam)
        });
        m_cThread.detach()
    }
```

> В таком случае, если я все правильно понимаю, функция someFunction
> завершается, значение szParam становится не определено, в то время как
> anotherFunction запущенное в отдельном потоке все еще может его
> использовать.

Не совсем правильно. Да функция завершается, но у самой строки (массива char) "Some Str" глобальное время жизни - пока работает программа. Переменная, которая является указателем `szParam` становится не определена, но Вы уже передали адрес строки в другой поток. И таким образом Вы дали другому потоку доступ к константной строке "Some Str". По стандарту константные объекты - потокобезопасны, т.е. читать их можно из нескольких потоков

Comment: *Вы уже передали адрес строки в другой поток* - не передали, в этом и проблема

Comment: Почему не передали? А это что - `anotherFunction(szParam)` ?

Comment: В примере с потоком создание потока происходит до вызова `anotherFunction` и при вызове ссылка на указатель (которая и передана в поток вместо передачи непосредственно значения указателя) может уже протухнуть.

Comment: Тут да, нужно передавать по значению.